# Background sizing for responsive site

Tags: jquery, html, css

thank you in advance for your patience im somewhat new to this and my code is still in development.  Im trying to build a responsive portfolio site, i have pieced together a responsive gallery, navigation that breaks to a dropdown menu for mobile and a bordered background that  is supposed to adjust using media queries, positioning underneath the nav but surrounding the gallery.

My problem is with the bordered background, which i have set up as img.bg, essentially im trying to swap images out and replace with img.bg2 & 3 when the size gets to standard screen sizes. To do this im using the visibility property in my style.css. I had it working somewhat and now its completely mixed up, any help and or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I posted my latest example online at: www.ververserver.com

cheers.

Comment: Please post the relevant bits of code here, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with tehAon, you're over complicating the whole matter!

```
background-size:cover;
```

New CSS3 property. Will always cover the specified element with the image. No matter the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be trying to over complicate this. Are you ok with using CSS3? They added a new attribute called background-size that will stretch and shrink your images.

Here is a link to some information
http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Also from w3cschools: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Browser Support:
"The background-size property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome, and Safari 5+."

Comment: Hey thanks guys! that works great for unified sizing, i'll play around with it a bit. my only problem is that I need the image to stretch down and become thinner on 1024px and again for mobile at 500px, thats why i was swaping images but maybe i can change the backgrounds on different resolutions? ill try it out, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So, I read this article as well which was good: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

and I have come up with a solution that seems to some what work at 500px and 1824px but at 1024px the background image becomes way larger than the original file, heres the code I have so far in the drop-basic.css file:

```
body { 
background-image: url("images/SQlarge.svg");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

@media only screen 
and (max-width : 1024px) 
{
body { 
background-image: url("images/SQ1024.svg");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
}

@media only screen 
and (max-width : 500px) 
{
body { 
background-image: url("images/SQmobile.svg");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
}

img, audio, video, canvas { max-width: 100%; }

.container { 
    max-width: 80em;
    width: 88%;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

You can see the site at www.ververserver.com, I appreciate any help with this! thanks